# Tagged VLAN not working on TP Link TL-SG1016PE

Tags: vlan, hpe, draytek

[Draytek AP 960C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbvyP.png)[TP Link Switches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scyGX.png)[HPE Switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPV4Y.png)[DrayTek 2866](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zD9A.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zD9A.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zD9A.png)I have created an additional VLAN upon my company network, configured exactly the same as VLAN's already in place. However this new VLAN does not work. WI-Fi devices are unable to connect to this VLAN (VLAN ID 40) of which I don not understand way. The other VLAN ID's 10,20,30 work fine accepting device connections accordingly via Wi-Fi and being assigned the corresponding SSID

The devices being used are a Draytek 2866 router, HPE 1920-48G Switch, 2 x TP Link TL-SG1016PE Switches & 4 x Draytek 960c AP's. The AP's are connected via PoE to the TP Link switches.

LAN Ports are tagged based to the switches.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

See images for configuration across all devices in question.

Comment: `See images for configuration across all devices in question` you've shown the configuration for a Draytek 2866, but your question seems to be about you not being able to set up a TP-LINK TL-SG1016PE - I happen to use one of those, and VLAN's work just fine - perhaps you did it wrong

Comment: I'm sorry for only the config for the DrayTek router showing. I do have configs for the HPE switch, TP Link switch & the DrayTek APs to upload. However when I drag and drop or browse to them, they appear to overwrite each other so that only one image appears. They are all PNG image files, assume they should be fine.

Comment: Also the failing VLAN upon the TP Link switch is configured exactly the same as the working VLAN's upon the switch.

Comment: Please add all relevant configurations to your question - if possible as text files using the editor's `{}` preformat function.

Comment: It turns out that I cannot post embedded images until i earn 10 reputations. So the following are links to images of all the configurations :-  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbvyP.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/scyGX.png
 [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPV4Y.png
 [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zD9A.png